# Return view to original position when ending UIView animation

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I have a very simple UIView animation, which causes my view to "throb":

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction+UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat+UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    CGAffineTransform transf = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, 1.05f, 1.05f);
    [self.view setTransform:transf];
} completion:nil];
```

At some point the user hits a button to cancel the animation, and apply a new transform.

```
[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
[self.view setTransform:aNewTransform];
```

I'd like it to reset to it's original transform, but instead it's getting increased in size by 5%.

Edit: I tried adding a completion block that resets the transform to it's original position. This works, but causes the transform I run immediately after to be trampled... the completion block gets run AFTER I apply `aNewTransform`.

Edit 2: I found a solution, using CABasicAnimation, instead of UIView animations. I would still be interested if anybody found a solution using UIView animations... I like the block-based interface better. This also only works, because I happen to be keeping track of my scale value separate from the one applied to the view. Everything that changes the scale uses a method that also changes `self.scale`

My replacement animation:

```
CABasicAnimation *basicAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
basicAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.scale*1.05f];
basicAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.scale];
basicAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
basicAnimation.duration = 0.2;
basicAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:basicAnimation forKey:@"Throb"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Before starting a new animation on an existing view, you can reset the view if any of these attributes were previously altered:

```
// first, don't forget to stop ongoing animations for the view
[theView.layer removeAllAnimations];

// if the view was hidden
theView.hidden = NO;

// if you applied a transformation e.g. translate, scale, rotate..., reset to identity
theView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

// if you changed the anchor point, this will reset it to the center of the view
theView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

// if you changed the alpha, this will reset it to visible
theView.alpha = 1.;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the line

```
[self.view setTransform:aNewTransform];
```

in the completion block.

Comment: Won't work. aNewTransform is hypothetical and can be a number of different transforms depending on which button the use presses. Won't know which until I'm removing the animation.